# In a grid built in javascript and html, how do I assign a new text-node value to all cells in the grid that fulfils a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am relatively new to DOM manipulation with JS and html. Here I am having to build a 10 * 10 grid, with sequential numbers in each cells representing its text node. And the requirement is that, when I click on any cell in the grid, if its text node value is 5 or a multiple of 5, then the text node of this cell and also  all other cells in the grid which are multiples of 5 should be replaced with a "**".

Here's my code till now, but I am just failing to implement the conditional replacement of the cell's text node value on a click event. And here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rohanpaul/xpvt214o/87630/)
Many thanks in advance.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Grid with random numbers</title>
  <style>
    #grid {
      margin: 10px;
      font-size: 1.25em;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
    }
    
    td {
      border: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="grid"></div>
  <script>
    let totalRows = 10;
    let cellsInRow = 10;
    let min = 1;
    let max = 100;

    function drawTable() {
      let cellNumber = 1;
      let grid = document.getElementById('grid');
      let tbl = document.createElement("table");


      // Create rows in the table
      for (var r = 0; r < totalRows; r++) {
        let row = document.createElement("tr");
        row.setAttribute('id', (r));

        // In each row now create cells
        for (var c = 0; c < cellsInRow; c++) {
          let cell = document.createElement("td");
          let cellText = document.createTextNode(cellNumber++);
          let cellFillingStar = document.createTextNode("**");

          // each cell should have its 'id' attribute set, as its corresponding cellText value
          cell.setAttribute('id', (cellNumber - 1));

          cell.appendChild(cellText);
          row.appendChild(cell);

          // Code to check that each cell got its 'id' attribute set, as its corresponding cellText value.
          cell.addEventListener(
            "click",
            function(e) {
              var id = e.target.id;
              if (id % 5 == 0) {
                $('.table').each(function() {
                  $(this).find('id').each(function() {
                    alert("Multiple of 5");
                    cell.appendChild(cellFillingStar);
                  })
                })
              }
            },
            false);
        }
        tbl.appendChild(row);
      }
      grid.appendChild(tbl);
    }
    window.onload = drawTable;
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there are some error in your script, like you're trying to loop on a .table object that doesn't exist, as table has no class.

I've tried to simplify it a little bit, using jquery.

the main snippet I've added is this one:

```
$( "#grid table tr td" ).on( "click", function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    if (id % 5 == 0) {
    $( "#grid table tr td" ).each(function( index ) {
        if ($(this).text() % 5 == 0) {
            $(this).text($(this).text()+'**');
      }
        });
  }
});
```

where you assign  the event to all td elements, and then, based on their content or id value, you change the text of all relevant td that are multiple of 5.

here is the full working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/88139/